# Inconsistency in sort order

Tags: bug, status-completed

If I execute the following API call:

```
http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions?sort=newest&body=True&pagesize=5&min=1275575777&order=desc
```

versus one that does not include the `min` parameter:

```
http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions?sort=newest&body=True&pagesize=5&order=desc
```

I get the items sorted descending for the first call (with the `min` param), but I get the sort ascending for the second one.

I'm guessing since I asked for them to be sorted descending, the issue is with the second call.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like without the `min` parameter, it's sorting *within* a single page of results in ascending order, while the page-by-page results are still descending.

By the way, specifying an `order` for `/questions` and `/questions/unanswered` doesn't do anything I believe.